# Mysql auto increment number in case there are a large of insertions

Tags: auto-increment

what does happening to get auto increment number when there is a large of insertions on the same time? for exemple we have 100 visitors add a posts on the same time (22:10:10 12/09/2013) how the Mysql Auto increment make unique ID for each post?

Comment: If it is auto-increment, index locking makes sure that each one gets it own unique value.

Comment: yes each one get own unique value but how?

Comment: The table keeps track of the auto-increment counter and has locking on it, so that only one request is handled at a time.  This does create a performance choke point.  For some applications they move to a more advanced external method for create unique ids that doesn't have the same performance characteristics under high load.

Comment: @bmorgan21 any docs about how does it work? not only autoincrement, I need to understand generaly how does databases systems work under a high load.